# Can I power a DC motor with the Pi's 5 volt pin?

Tags: power, safety, pi-b+

The Pi has a 5 volt output. This [DC motor](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2941) draws about 600 mA when it is stalled. Is it safe to power the DC motor using the Pi's 5 volt output pin? If not, can I power it with a microusb charger?

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT try to power it from a GPIO.

Yes, you can power the motor from the 5V pin (although it looks like a servo the blurb makes clear it is just an ordinary DC motor in a servo like housing).

However, if you do so the motor will run at a fixed speed in a fixed direction.

If you want to control the direction and/or speed you will need to connect it via a motor driver board, google for L9110S or L298N.

Comment: I have a mosfit transistor.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the mosfet?

Comment: control whether the motor gets voltage or not.

Comment: So power via the 5V pin but switched by a mosfet connected to a GPIO? You probably need a protection diode as well to stop back EMF killing the mosfet.  That will give you speed control if you use PWM on the GPIO.  This seems to be becoming a different question.

Comment: the question is can a power a motor through the 5 V gpio pin. I didn't ask about control, but you brought it up.

Comment: Which I have already  answered, Yes.  The 5V pin is NOT a GPIO.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the max amperage the 5 V pin can produce. (You have answered my question; I'm just wondering if there is a citation that I can safely draw 600 mA.)

Comment: I power my Pis via the 5V and ground pins so the limit is what the power supply can give minus that needed by the Pi and other peripherals.  If you power via the microUSB socket the limit is the polyfuse (1.2 amps for old Pis, 2.2 amp for new Pis) minus that needed by the Pi and peripherals.

Comment: Okay. (What are the consequences of drawing too much current from the 5 V pin?)

Comment: The pi will reset.

Answer (score 0):

well there is a way to power a DC motor with only 5 volts from GPIO pins.
first you will deed a 5 volt motor and and attach a small arm or Popsicle stick and make the arm face a button, that button controls the negative side of a different power source that matches the voltage of your DC motor to that when you make the 5V motor turn to press the button it allows the power from a different power source to power your DC motor. you will have to code the motor to be inverted when you do not want the DC motor to go forward.